# CSS Responsive Container with nested container

Tags: html, css, web

I am fairly new to coding.
I tried to do a responsive `div` container with a smaller nested container in it. Can anyone provide some guidance?

The Chicken Beef and Sushi needs to be inside the main container to the top right. *Where am I going wrong?*

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}   

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p    {
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 10.5px
        
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <title>Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column 1">
        <div id="chicken">Chicken</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eu fermentum diam. Nam vitae tellus sed augue commodo tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec id purus justo. Proin dignissim ligula nisl. Quisque eleifend, turpis vitae suscipit hendrerit, sem massa faucibus nunc, vel condimentum velit nibh at leo. Vivamus luctus facilisis faucibus. Aenean id rhoncus orci. Nullam feugiat lorem eros, at condimentum nibh lobortis a. Mauris finibus fringilla aliquet. Nam semper feugiat ante ac posuere. Curabitur ac magna vitae velit maximus convallis tristique eu nulla. Integer non commodo lectus, ut varius ipsum. Nunc ut volutpat magna</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column 2">
        <div id="beef">Beef</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eu fermentum diam. Nam vitae tellus sed augue commodo tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec id purus justo. Proin dignissim ligula nisl. Quisque eleifend, turpis vitae suscipit hendrerit, sem massa faucibus nunc, vel condimentum velit nibh at leo. Vivamus luctus facilisis faucibus. Aenean id rhoncus orci. Nullam feugiat lorem eros, at condimentum nibh lobortis a. Mauris finibus fringilla aliquet. Nam semper feugiat ante ac posuere. Curabitur ac magna vitae velit maximus convallis tristique eu nulla. Integer non commodo lectus, ut varius ipsum. Nunc ut volutpat magna</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column 3">
        <div id="sushi">Sushi</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eu fermentum diam. Nam vitae tellus sed augue commodo tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec id purus justo. Proin dignissim ligula nisl. Quisque eleifend, turpis vitae suscipit hendrerit, sem massa faucibus nunc, vel condimentum velit nibh at leo. Vivamus luctus facilisis faucibus. Aenean id rhoncus orci. Nullam feugiat lorem eros, at condimentum nibh lobortis a. Mauris finibus fringilla aliquet. Nam semper feugiat ante ac posuere. Curabitur ac magna vitae velit maximus convallis tristique eu nulla. Integer non commodo lectus, ut varius ipsum. Nunc ut volutpat magna</
```

Comment: try you add "float: left;" to the .row class.

Comment: Where is your `"main container"` (You talk about `.row`)? Maybe add a screenshot of the result you want. In general, it is better to use a flexbox -or- CSS grid (float trick is little "out of date" related to columns & responsive layout).

Comment: You should edit your question, it's not clear what you really want. Should these three terms be right-aligned with the boxes below them?

Answer (score 5):

Use flexbox, it allows you to position your elements in rows or columns. Grid is also a good alternative.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

Remove float: left

```css
.column {
  width: 33.33%
}
```

To make it even more responsive, you could optionally add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.row`, so when the window is resized enough, it will drop a column to the next row.

Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox